# Barcode Label Printer (MUST auto generate unique id)

Tags: printer, barcode-scanner

I am in need of a label printer that can be configured to generate unique IDs for barcodes without having to edit the ID for each label manually (the demonstrations I have seen online will edit it individual while creating a template so I am uncertain if this is possible). e.g. print 1000 labels assigning each one a unique ID.

I would like the labels to be small enough to fit on a mouse.
Price below £300 would be nice.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Barcode editing is done in software, not hardware. The printer will do whatever the software tells it to do. I don't have direct links because it's been a few years, but using Dymo's SDK you can generate a barcode at will. Designing the software to make it unique is something you/your team has to do though.

Comment: @Andy Many label printers, especially industrial, have such functions incorporated into their firmware. So it is reasonable for the OP to request it. But the model I worked with has a price 10x OPs budget.

Comment: Hm. Good point. I didn't think about industrial ones due to the budget. I was thinking small label printers. I stand corrected though. Thanks Jan.